# Count Iterator only Appending final count value

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, counter

I have a loop that assigns strings inside an xml file that's been parsed with BeautifulSoup

```
count = 0
for i in oosASINS:

 sku = str(i)
 message.sku.string = sku
 message.quantity.string = "0"
 stringnum = str(count)
 message.messageid.string = stringnum    
 messages.append(message)
 count +=1
```

It should make a document where the message id assigned to each new set of messages is iterated by one (0,1,2...etc) but instead it only appends 1-the final count value so instead I am getting (65,65,65...) where the final count value is 66.

I am confused about this because the count doesn't increment until after the previous count variable has been assigned as a messageid, yet it manages to always output 65

Comment: reusing the same reference of `message`, a classic. Instantiate a new `message` object in your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not creating another `message` instance in your loop because of

```
messages.append(message)
```

your `messages` list contains 65 times the same reference to the `message` object, bearing the last value you assigned to it.

Without knowing how `message` is created I could advise you to do:

```
messages.append(copy.deepcopy(message))
```

but the best way is to create a new `message` in your loop.

Comment: I ended up having to rewrite the code to make a new "message" because it was originally hard-coded into the software. It worked after that though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a new instance of message inside your loop